# Datatable make row with named ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable created with datatable.js.

I am trying to dynamically add a row to it.
After looking at the documentation, I am getting the [error](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) "Requested unknown parameter "ID" for row n"

The error page has not helped me resolve this.

I set up my table using an object and columns with names:

```
{ "title": "ID", "data": "ObjID", "className": "dt-center" },
{ "title": "Name", "data": "ObjName", "className": "dt-center" }
```

And I have tried adding my code two different ways (per conflicting (outdated?) documentation), both resulting in the same error.

```
//I have columns. This is both methods I have tried.
dataTable.DataTable().row.add(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']);
dataTable.fnAddData(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']);
```

I've read the documentation, but am not finding any solutions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sourcier found the answer about halfway down [this](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/6736/requested-unknown-parameter-after-add-new-row) page!
(Oddly enough, I think I remember reading a question a few days ago with almost an identical answer. Good on youu, Sourcier).

Basically, I need to do a JSON object and return that using fnadddata()

`var Json = {
                     "image" : values[0],
                    "id" :  values[1],
                    "name" : values[2]
}
var rtn = oTable.fnAddData(Json );`

Comment: Is this an answer or a new question?

Comment: Fair point. It started as an answer, and then I found that it didn't perfectly work. I'll edit the question part out into a new question.